# Which Java data structure move the position of the last retrieved element?

Tags: java, data-structures

I used to understand a bunch of Java data structures but did not use it for a while. I am looking for two data structures.

1. the data structure that moves the position of the last retrieved element to the LAST position.
2. the data structure that moves the position of the last retrieved element
   to the FIRST position.

I have tried to look for them on the Internet and saw e.g. LinkedList, ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet ect. They all provide the description and how to implement them but not the two points I mentioned above. Thus which are those two Java data structure?

Comment: Are you looking for `Queue` and `Stack`?

Comment: I think he (or she) asked about FIFO. I am expecting good answer :D very good question

Comment: What I know about Queue is "First In, First Out", and Stack is "Last In, First Out". Does Queue or Stack provide one of the two above functionality?

Answer (score 4):

See java.util.LinkedHashMap, from API: it is possible to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently (access-order).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a fixed-size data structure, please consider using the [`LRUMap` from Apache Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap.html).

This is half an answer, though, since an LRUMap-like structure only accomplishes #2 of your requirements.

For #1, you need an MRUMap-like structure (MRU stands for most-recently-used). As a guide, refer to this [`LinkedHashMap`-based implementation](http://eclipse.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.2.2-6.1/MRUMap_8java-source.html), whose drawback is that only the `put()` operation is considered as an access.